# How to convert a String to Date of format yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:ss

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I have a String like `"2015-07-16 17:07:21"` . I want to convert it into a Date of same format. I tried something like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:ss");
Date date = sdf.parse("2015-07-16 17:07:21");
```

But output was different format like `Thu Jul 16 17:00:21 IST 2015`. How can I get it work as i need. can anyone help me. I know this might be a duplicate but i didn't find any luck.

Comment: a date does not have a format, it has a value representing a point in time. if you want to display it in some format you should use SimpleDateFormat

Comment: How can i do that. Can you please give me an example or a link to refer?

Comment: When you want it to be formatted different, define another SimpleDateformat with the pattern you need and format the date with it. To be clear: You have one SimpleDateformat parsing the input and one for printing the output.

Comment: At least two answers have sort of stated this, let me make it more explicit: A Date does not "have a format". A date is a (big) integer, the number of milliseconds since a time in the past. SimpleDateFormat is one (easy) way to either transform a String from a particular format into a date (with `parse()`), or transform a Date into a String (with `format()`).

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the Java API https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

> The class Date represents a specific instant in time, with millisecond precision.

Try to understand the difference/connection of `Date` and `DateFormat`.

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws ParseException{
    String dateString = "2015-07-16 17:07:21";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    // use SimpleDateFormat to define how to PARSE the INPUT
    Date date = sdf.parse(dateString);

    // at this point you have a Date-Object with the value of
    // 1437059241000 milliseconds
    // It doesn't have a format in the way you think

    // use SimpleDateFormat to define how to FORMAT the OUTPUT
    System.out.println( sdf.format(date) );

    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat();
    System.out.println( sdf.format(date) );

  // ....
}
```

Output: (Please note that the Date stays the same, just its representation (format) changes)

```
2015-07-16 17:07:21
7/16/15 5:07 PM
```

Comment: `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());` to remove warning of locale.

Answer (score 0):

try format string like: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

M : month, m: minute

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    String dateString = "2015-07-16 17:07:21";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date;
    try {
        date = sdf.parse(dateString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    } 
    System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
    System.out.println(dateString.equals(sdf.format(date)));
}
```

also, a date does not have a format, it has a value representing a point in time. if you want to display it in some format you should use SimpleDateFormat

Comment: I tried. it's not working

Comment: sdf.format(date) returns the String again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String dateInString = "2015-07-16 17:07:21";
    try {

        Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);

        System.out.println(date);
        System.out.println(formatter.format(date));

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Thu Jul 16 17:07:21 IST 2015
2015-07-16 17:07:21
```

**Note:**
For complete date and time patterns, please refer to this  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score -1):

See this code:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    String dateString = "2015-07-16 17:07:21";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date;
    try {
        date = sdf.parse(dateString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    } 
    System.out.println(date); // Displays date in it's default format Jul 16 17:00:21 IST 2015
    System.out.println(dateString.equals(date)); // Returns false since 'Jul 16 17:00:21 IST 2015' is not equal to dateString (2015-07-16 17:07:21)
}
```

Date class always stores date in its default format. The `SimpleDateFormat` helps to format date using its object. It doesn't make any changes to the date class object. Rather it converts the `Date class` to `User defined` format which doesn't have any effect on the Date class object. I guess it is clear.