# SimpleDateFormat parse to date correct pattern

Tags: android, date

I'm wondering what is the correct pattern to parse `2018-05-21 23:05:51` to `Date` object using `simpleDateFormat.parse` method

Comment: `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`?

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a String to Date of format yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:ss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38410976/how-to-convert-a-string-to-date-of-format-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss)