# Convert Java Date from one format to another without converting it into string

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, simpledateformat, date

I am trying to get my current system date and am formatting it into Etc/UTC and then into this "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm z" format. The problem is this that the format function after formatting the date returns a string instead of date. Here is the code spinet below

```
    final Date currentDate = new Date();
    final SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm z");
    dateFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
    String finalDateTime=  dateFormatter.format(currentDate);
    System.out.println(finalDateTime);
```

Is there any alternative solution which allows me to format the date by keeping me within this date object because I have researched every date library after java 8 and before java 8, it seems like if I want to format any type of date or dateTime, I have to use a formatter  which converts the given date into string.

Any Alternative solutions or it is not possible?

Comment: ...no you can't get a Date with a specific format!

Comment: What exactly do you want? Doo you want to CONVERT the date? Why not getting the information in the final output that you need?

Comment: Do you want to change the timezone?

Comment: You can change the timezone but there's no point of changing the date to me? If you need to do so , create a new date instance.

Comment: You are confusing a Date with its String representation. It's as if you're asking to use doubles that always print with 2 decimals -- numbers don't understand decimals or printing, only a formatter does.

Comment: Possible duplicate of (1) [return date type with format in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50485203/return-date-type-with-format-in-java), (2) [Change the format of Date Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18628059/change-the-format-of-date-java), …

Comment: … (3) [SimpleDateFormatter.parse giving output in different format than specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50494859/simpledateformatter-parse-giving-output-in-different-format-than-specified) and (4) [How to convert a String to Date of format yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:ss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38410976/how-to-convert-a-string-to-date-of-format-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss).

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. `Date` and `TimeZone`are outdated too. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Date` represents a single point in time. That's it, nothing more, nothing less. It does *not* contain any information about time zones.

`Wed Jun 06 12:38:15 BST 2018` is the same `Date` (instant) as `Wed Jun 06 11:38:15 GMT 2018`, just in a different time zone. It's like the words "humans" and "homo sapians". They refer to the same species, they are just kind of in a different "format".

So you don't need to change the date in any way. You just need to format it differently. This is why formatters return `String`s. Only `String`s can represent one particular *format* of a date.

Comment: If I understood your concept, you mean to say that date will always remain the date but formatter will be its Beacon , beacon will come in different shapes but date will always remain the same as an entity. Just like human and clothes , human can  wear different clothes  but at the end that human is the same human