# Object to Date formatting in Java

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, date-format

I have a big problem with a date that I have to formatting in the right way. My proposal of solution following:

```
...
//Read: 1935-05-12 00:00:00.0
Date dateOfBirth= (Date) arrayOfObject[3];

//Pattern: dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");

//12-05-1935 12:00:00 (for me it's perfect but I need Date and no String)  
String strDate = dateFormat.format(dateOfBirth);  

//Read: Sun May 12 00:00:00 CET 1935
dateOfBirth= dateFormat.parse(strDate);

//Read: Sun May 12 00:00:00 CET 1935
rep.setDateOfBirth(dateOfBirth);
...
```

I need a format like ***strDate***, because I need this format for the database, but I need a Date and not a String and I don't know how can I formatting in the right way my Date string.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You have a `Date` already. A `Date` is a moment in time. The *representation* of a date can be a string.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [display Java.util.Date in a specific format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262310/display-java-util-date-in-a-specific-format). Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50719313/convert-java-date-from-one-format-to-another-without-converting-it-into-string)?

Comment: Since you get `1935-05-12 00:00:00.0`, it looks like you are really getting a `java.sql.Timestamp` object out of your array. It’s another poorly deigned and long outdated class, a subclass of `Date` and a true hack on top of it.

Comment: Also pleas explain, when the time of day in the original object was 00:00:00.0, how can 12:00:00 be perfect?

Answer (score -1):

You can store the Date as is in the DB, and then after you retrieve it, you can convert it to whatever format you need for the DTO level.

Comment: Indeed, if you’ve got a database, then you can. Does it answer the question? How? (Not your downvoter)